# I don't understand how this comparison in JavaScript works

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

Consider the following variable `href` :

```
var href = element.attr('href');
```

I have come across conditions that look like this :

```
href && href.indexOf('javascript') == -1 ? TRUE : FALSE
```

Can anyone explain how this comparison works or why anyone would do this?

Comment: Its a ternary operation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: if you href exists and it contains it doesn't contain javascript return true if  else return false, seems a bit wierd unless thats out of context there should be something that value is supposed to be used for

Comment: I'm guessing it's looking to see if a link starts with `"javascript:"` and will execute code when clicked, rather than navigating somewhere.  Without more context it's impossible to say for sure though.

Comment: The useful `if true ? true : false`

Comment: thank u all.. from all this comments, can i consider that href and href.indexOf('javascript') == -1 need to be valid to get the result as true if not false. Like if href has value and href.idexof doesn't have string javascript then we will get the result has false. correct me if i'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

#### Meaning

Your comparison literally means this :

1. If `href` exists
2. and the `href` is a string that does not contain substring 'javascript'

   - then, return `TRUE`
   - else, return `FALSE`

---

#### Components

It consists of the following components :

1. **`href`** : 
   will have [**a truthy value**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) if `href` exists
2. **[`href.indexOf('javascript') == -1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)** : 
   will be `TRUE` if "javascript" is not a substring of string `href`
3. [**`A && B`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) : 
   returns `TRUE` if both `A` and `B` have a truthy value
4. [**`X ? Y : Z`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) : 
   returns `Y` if `X` has a truthy value and `Z` if it doesn't

---

#### Use case

Why would anyone do this, you may ask? Why would anyone look for the string `javascript` inside the `href` of an `<a>` tag, you may ask?

Well, consider the following HTML :

```html
<a href="javascript:alert('Hello World')">Click me</a>
```

Now, all this does, is trigger an `alert()` when you click on that link. While this is pretty harmless, this same technique can be used by a hacker to run all kinds of malicious code.

Although it's not exactly a bulletproof solution, the comparison `href && href.indexOf('javascript') == -1 ? TRUE : FALSE` is almost certainly used to find such malicious code and remove it.

Answer (score -1):

var href = attribute of some element ( a link redirected to )

x ? y : z syntax is shorthand for if (x) { y } else { z }

if href exists on element AND
if href is not some javascript code (ex. javascript:alert('haha')) true else false. In this example second line is probably assigned to some variable.

Comment: thank u all.. from all this comments, can i consider that href and href.indexOf('javascript') == -1 need to be valid to get the result as true if not false. Like if href has value and href.idexof doesn't have string javascript then we will get the result has false. correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Its a ternary operation.

```
var href = element.attr('href');
console.log(href && href.indexOf('javascript') == -1 ? true : false);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
var href = element.attr('href');
if(href && href.indexOf('javascript') == -1) {
    console.log(true);
} else {
    console.log(false);
}
```

You can see an example of how it works with a test string here:  https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/ha6kh93c/

With more information in the developer docs:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Hope that helps!